# Canadian postal codes wrong when using Google geocoding API (ver. 3)

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am trying to geocode Canadian addresses using Google geocoding API ver. 3, for example a Toronto address:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=270%20cassandra%20blvd,%20Toronto,%20ON&sensor=false

The Canadian **postal code** is often wrong. How come? I saw other posts describing the same problem, back from 2011.
These are North American addresses, I think Google should get them right at least for US and Canada.

Thank you,
M.R.

Comment: Unless there's a mistake in your API call - and I can't see one if there is - I doubt we can help. I think you'll have to just report it on the map UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please let me know the site address  where I can report the issue?

Comment: If you go to the main maps site, https://maps.google.com/?q=270%20Cassandra%20Boulevard,%20Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada, there's a link "Report Problem" in the bottom-right corner

Comment: Ok, I did that but there are probably thousands of wrong Canadian postal codes, other developers are complaining about this issue..

Comment: 2017 and still 90% of the Canada postal codes returned by the api are not correct.